# How do I find the PID of the active window, where the application is a flatpak?

Tags: linux, process, window

I can find the information easily for regular applications with something like:

```
xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname
xdotool getactivewindow getwindowpid
```

> VLC media player
>
> 28448

However with the Flatpak I get:

```
xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname
xdotool getactivewindow getwindowpid
```

> VLC media player
>
> 2

So the PID comes back as something odd like 2, 0 or nothing at all depending on the app.

I haven't been able to find a way to do this with xdotool or anything else.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with flatpak, but here's a guess: because of the sandboxing/vm, it may actually be `0` or `2`. But I'm not entirely sure what's going on. Have you tried manually spotting the process with `ps` or `pstree`?

Comment: also, you could try `flatpak ps` - it actually should show the PID fo the wrapper process, etc...

Comment: Looking again at VLC as an example, it has a 'Name' of `rcu_gp`, 'PID' of 3, and 'Window Title' of `VLC media player`. `flatpak ps` shows me 'Instance' of 2707785125, 'PID' of `4603`, 'Application' of `org.videolan.VLC`, 'Runtime' of `org.kde.Platform`. With the PID 3 & Name `rcu_gp` how do I connect this as belonging to the flatpak ps output? The Window Title is unreliable; for example with Flatseal there is no window title

Comment: If you have multiple windows open, the PID will also remain `2`. It might not be possible to possible to link it to a pid that way as they all have the same, as far as i can see. You might be seeing the PID of the sandboxed process. If you run `flatpak enter $instanceid /bin/bash` and run `ps -aux` there, you'll see that `/app/bin/vlc.bin` actually has PID 2. The `WINDOWID` in `cat /proc/2/environ` matches the console the flatpak command is run in (and not the vlc window). Running `pstree` on your console should give you an overview.

Comment: So I think that the window is being created by the console/instance you run flatpak from (but in a sandbox) and that seems to be the reason why it shows 2 (otherwise I'd expect it to show the console pid and I thnik it technically should be the console pid). This could also either be a bug or a feature of X/flatpak.